# Logstash date filter maps AM/PM in timestamp fields to same value in Elasticsearch

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, datefilter

I am using Logstash to send time-series data from csv files to Elasticsearch (fun stuff right!).

So, this is my date filter in Logstash:

```
date{
        match => ["Timestamp", "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a"]
        target => "@timestamp"
        }
```

I think this filter says: if 'Timestamp' field has value of format 'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss' or 'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a', map it to 
'@timestamp'.

Now the values I received were ONLY of form `'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a'` and Logstash threw no `_dateparse` errors during the mapping. In Elasticsearch, I see that 2 documents with different AM/PM`'Timestamp'` have the same `'@timestamp'` value.

Case in point:

2 documents of `"Timestamp": "12/16/2017 11:00:00 PM"` and `"Timestamp": "12/16/2017 11:00:00 AM"` have ES `"@timestamp": "2017-12-16T16:00:00.000Z"`.

Why didnt ES throw a versioning error? How do I fix this issue? Is this because I am checking for both types of date formats?

Thanks

Comment: I think the same problem was solved in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783690/6113627

Comment: I've done a test with the solution linked above and it seem to work. Short answer: replace `H` with `k`. Long answer: see linked answer.

Comment: "k" would be for a 24-hour clock, but your example of "11:00:00 PM" is not a 24-hour clock.  If your formats always include AM/PM, then you should be using the "a" pattern (as your first/only match).

Comment: Thanks Alan and baudsp. I am curious - what if the incoming data is of 2 different but similar formats ( as mentioned in my example). Would Logstash just map it to the first similar pattern( even though the exact format to map to is available)? Wouldn't this be a potential bug or is my logic wrong here?